# For what values of $a$ are the curves tangental to each other?

Tags: calculus

So we have the functions $$\begin{array}{lcl}y & = & ax^2+ax+\frac{1}{24} \ \ \ \ (1) \\x & = & ay^2+ay+\frac{1}{24} \ \ \ \ (2) \\\end{array}$$ and I want to find all the values of $a$ for which the curves are tangental to eachother.

Differentiating both I get $$\begin{array}{lcl}y' & = & 2ax+a \\x' & = & 2ayy'+ay' \\\end{array}$$

Now I need to find where these derivatives are equal, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: If both equalities are differentiated wrt $x$, then $x'=1$.

Comment: You will want to look at the $x$ derivative in both cases, *or* the $y$ derivative in both cases. Comparing the $x$ derivative of one with the $y$ derivative of the other doesn't make much sense (try to picture the situation for a simple curve mirrored at the line representing the identity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The curves are mirrored on the axis $y=x$. So we must have a tangent a some point with $x=y$ and $y' = \pm1$. So we have

a) for $y' = 1$:

$$ \alpha ( 2x+1) = 1
$$
and 
$$
x =  ax^2+ax+\frac{1}{24} 
$$
Solving  these two equations for $x$ and $\alpha$ gives the solution for $x>0$:

$ \alpha = 2/3$ (with $x = 1/4$)

b) EDIT: Further solution for $y' = -1$:

$\alpha =  13/12 - \sqrt{601}/12  \simeq  -0.9596
$ (with $x \simeq 0.0211$)

EDIT: There are further solutions with $x<0$:

a) for $y' = 1$:

$\alpha = 3/2$ (with $x= - 1/6 \simeq   -0.1667$)

b) for $y' = -1$:

$\alpha =  13/12 + \sqrt{601}/12 \simeq 3.1263
$ (with $x \simeq - 0.6599$)

Comment: What is $\alpha?$ I assume it's just an $a$. So the only point of tangent occurs when $a=2/3?$ Plotting these and varying $a$ from -10 to 10 seems to give more tangental points. https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: And how is $x=ax^2+ax+1/24?$ Eq (2) is $x=ay^2+ay+1/24.$

Comment: Your second question: with $\alpha = 2/3$ and $x=1/4$ we have from eq. (1): $y =  1/4$. Putting that into eq. (2) gives again  $x = ay^2+ay+\frac{1}{24} = 1/4$ so eq. (2) is satisfied. But that was clear in the first place, since we were demanding $y=x$ and  eqns. (1) and (2) are the same under exchange of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I looked at it again and indeed there are more solutions. I am sorry I have overlooked them earlier. They are now added in  the text.

Answer (score 1):

In Equation 2:
$$y'=\frac{1}{2ay+a}\tag{i}$$

For them to be tangential to each other, their $y'$ should be equal at the point of intersection for the two curves .

$$2ax+a=\frac{1}{2ay+a}$$

And $$y-x=a(x-y)(x+y)+a(x-y)\tag{(1)-(2)}$$
$$-1=a(x+y)+a\tag{ii}$$

You have two equations to calculate $(x,y)$ i.e. the point of intersection. Thats it!

Comment: Great, thank you buddy!